# How can I print the phrase as the randomly generated numbers?

Tags: python, pandas

Code:

```
import string, random
import pandas as pd
#User Input
title = input("Please Enter A Title For This Puzzle: ")
if len(title) == 0:
    print("String is empty")
    quit()

phrase = input("Please Enter A Phrase To Be Encoded: ")
if len(phrase) == 0:
    print("String is empty")
    quit()


#Numbers get assigned to the letters
nums = random.sample(range(1, 27), 26)
code = dict(zip(nums, string.ascii_lowercase))

#'Start' of Puzzle for the user  
print ("The Title Of This Puzzle Is", title)


#Code for Grid



code2 = {'Number': [[nums[0]],[nums[1]],[nums[2]],[nums[3]],[nums[4]],[nums[5]],[nums[6]],[nums[7]],[nums[8]],[nums[9]],[nums[10]],[nums[11]],[nums[12]],[nums[13]],[nums[14]],[nums[15]],[nums[16]],[nums[17]],[nums[18]],[nums[19]],[nums[20]],[nums[21]],[nums[22]],[nums[23]],[nums[24]],[nums[25]]],
        'Letter': list(string.ascii_lowercase),
        }




df = pd.DataFrame(code2, columns = ['Number', 'Letter'])

print (df)
```

What I am currently trying to do is take the phrase that has been entered and spit out the randomly generated numbers, under the #Numbers Get Assigned To The Letter comment, instead.
E.g: Hello = 20-1-16-16-19

I have already tried but the code im writing is nonsense and would like some outside help

Thank you

Comment: Sorry, I'm having a bit of trouble understanding what you are trying to do, and reading your code. Could you clarify for everyone a bit?

Comment: So what i would like help is, converting the letters in the user inputed phrase into the random numbers that are linked to them, you can see this if you take the code and run it, it comes up with a table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, is it something like this you were looking for?

flip the nums position

```
code = dict(zip(string.ascii_lowercase, nums))
code.update({" ":0})
HELLO = [code[item] for item in "hello"]
```

Comment: yes this works but what about other phrases, can i change it to be,  HELLO =[code[item] for item in phrase], also it doesn't account for spaces?

Comment: Yes you can, no it will not count for space in current scenario

Comment: If you want to add spaces, you can do something like this then , ```code.update({" ":0}) ``` , before the ```HELLO =``` part.
0 can be any value you want to assign for space or if you want to completely remove space from your phrase you can ```phrase.replace(" ", "")```

Comment: Works perfect now, i don't know why... but i'll take it. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the optimal solution but it works. Hope it helps.

```py
def encode(phrase):     #Takes a phrase and returns the encoded result
    result = []
    for char in phrase:
        result.append(str(code_dict[char.lower()]))
    return '-'.join(result)

nums = random.sample(range(1, 27), 26)  #Creating lists of the random number and letters
letters = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
code_dict = {}

for i in range(len(letters)):    #Creating a dict relating the letters to a number
    key = letters[i]
    value = nums[i]
    code_dict[key] = value

encode(phrase)    #Encoding the phrase
```

Comment: You can just use `list(phrase)` instead of `split(phrase)` :) - in fact, you don't have to convert the string to a list anyway, as they're already iterable - you can do `for char in phrase` :)

Comment: Thank you, this works for world like 'hello' and 'goodbye' but cannot for sentences like 'hi mate'. i think it has to do with the spaces, right? what can be done for this? Error(sorry for format):       `Please Enter A Title For This Puzzle: Hello
Please Enter A Phrase To Be Encoded: hi there
The Title Of This Puzzle Is Hello
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 48, in <module>
    encode(phrase)    #Encoding the phrase
  File "main.py", line 36, in encode
    result.append(str(code_dict[char.lower()]))
KeyError: ' '`

Comment: If you want to add more possible characters rather than just lowercase letters then you will need to append them to the letters list and also extend the nums list to be the space length. The error you are currently getting is because ‘ ‘ isn’t in the letters list and hence not in the code_dict